# How to determine which subitem is touched in a ListView with setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android

I have an activity with a ListView and CustomAdapter to populate it.  Each item in the ListView has a ViewView and a few TextViews.  All that code it working fine.  My question is with my setOnItemClickListener.  Is it possible to determine which subitem was touched; i.e. the VideoView vs one of the TextViews?  Seems like onItemClick only gives me the main item position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You need to modify your `getView()` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

    CustomWrapper wrapper = null;
    if (view == null) {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_view, parent, false);
        wrapper = new CustomWrapper(view);
        view.setTag(wrapper);
    } else {
        wrapper = (CustomWrapper) view.getTag();
    }

    wrapper.yourSubView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()   
    {               
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Code to be handled on that particular subview
    }
}
```